# Im having problems passing my image to next activity, it seems like the image is not loading into the variable in time

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I pass the image but only the text to next activity but not d image
my data retriever it gives me a 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference

```
try {
                                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONArray innerJsonArray = response.getJSONArray(i);

                                    for (int j = 0; j < innerJsonArray.length(); j++) {
                                        jo = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                                        int id = jo.getInt("id");
                                        String name = jo.getString("name");
                                        String description = jo.getString("description");
                                        String imageUrl = jo.getString("imgthumb");
                                        String image = jo.getString("image");
                                        String prov = jo.getString("province");
                                        String type = jo.getString("type");

                                        if(prov.equals(provinceSelected)) {

                                            teacher = new Teacher(name, description, PHP_MYSQL_SITE_URL + "images/thumb/" + imageUrl, PHP_MYSQL_SITE_URL + "images/" + image);
                                            teachers.add(teacher);
                                        }
```

my intent

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Picasso.get().load(teacher.getImg()).into(new Target() {
                        @Override
                        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

                            bigImage = bitmap;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                        }
                    });
                    //preparing image to pass to next activity
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bigImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
                    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                    //****************************************************************************

                    Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayListView.this, Detail.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Name", teacher.getName());
                    intent.putExtra("Image", b);
                    intent.putExtra("Desc", teacher.getDescription());
```

Any help welcome. Thanks

Comment: move all your logic below `//preparing image to pass to next activity` into `Target::onBitmapLoaded` method - this anonymous class has asynchronous callback methods.  This might work for small images, but will still probably fail for medium to large images (binder transaction failure).  Consider persisting the image to filesDir, and passing the saved filename as a `String` in your intent.  I also suggest any I/O work is done off the main thread, and probably a try..catch..finally, closing the `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: Where's the PHP and/or MySQL part of this question?

Comment: it works thanks, I cant accept your answer, there is no place to accept.

Comment: Glad that worked. Although it solves your use case now, I wouldn't be happy writing the solution as an answer, as mentioned in my comments my suggestions still stand. I feel this would still be prone to failure, and I/O work on the main thread is not good practise for others to learn from.

Comment: thanks I will follow your advice